# How do I add an AsyncTask to this?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, web-services, android-asynctask

I am creating a Android app and I am fairly new to threading in general I have two different methods that I use to call two different webservices as shown below, so how do I change these to use the AsyncTask to run on a background thread?

My Code:

```
public List<String> getEvacRouteNames(){
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }


    BufferedReader in = null;
    String page;

    try {


        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost();
        request.setURI(URI)
        //Add The parameters.  The asmx webservice requires a double but gets posted as a string in a text field
        List<NameValuePair> nameValPairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(0);
        request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValPairs));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);

        }
        in.close();
        page = sb.toString();


        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(page)));
        // normalize the document
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        // get the root node
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("string");
        // the  node has three child nodes
        for (int n = 0; n < nodeList.getLength(); n++) {
            Node node=nodeList.item(n);
            String upperNode = node.getNodeName();
            Node temp=node.getChildNodes().item(n);
            if (upperNode.equals("string")){
                String routeName = node.getTextContent();
                routeNamesList.add(node.getTextContent());
            }
        }

        //System.out.println(page); 
        } catch (Exception E) {  
            E.printStackTrace();  
        } 
    finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return routeNamesList;
}

public EvacRoute getEvacuationRoute(String routeName, LatLng currentLocation, String lat, String lon) throws URISyntaxException, ClientProtocolException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException{
    evacRouteList = new ArrayList<EvacRoute>();
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    EvacRoute evacRoute = new EvacRoute();
    evacRoute.setDestinationName(routeName);
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String page;
    latslngsList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    try {

        latslngsList.add(currentLocation);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost();
        request.setURI(URI)
        //Add The parameters.  The asmx webservice requires a double but gets posted as a string in a text field
        List<NameValuePair> nameValPairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Route_Name", routeName));
        nameValPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("In_Lat", lat));
        nameValPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("In_Lon", lon));
        request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValPairs));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);

        }
        in.close();
        page = sb.toString();


        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(page)));
        // normalize the document
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        // get the root node
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("simple_ll_waypoint");
        double latitude = 0;
        double longitude= 0;
        // the  node has three child nodes
        for (int n = 0; n < nodeList.getLength(); n++) {
            String latString = "";
            String longString = "";

            Node node=nodeList.item(n);
            String upperNode = node.getNodeName();
            StringBuilder addressStrBlder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
                Node temp=node.getChildNodes().item(i);
                String nodeName = temp.getNodeName();
                String nodevalue = temp.getNodeValue();
                if(temp.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Lat")){
                    latString = temp.getTextContent();
                    latitude = Double.parseDouble(latString);

                } else if(temp.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Lon")){
                    longString = temp.getTextContent();
                    longitude = Double.parseDouble(longString);
                    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    latslngsList.add(latlng);
                } 

            }
            //Log.e("Fuel Stop", fuelStop.toString());
        }

        //System.out.println(page); 
        } catch (Exception E) {  
            E.printStackTrace();  
        } 
    finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    evacRoute.setLatLngList(latslngsList);
    evacRouteList.add(evacRoute);
    return evacRoute;
}
```

Comment: @c49 I appreciate that but this was answered 6 years ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend your class from `AsyncTask` and do like this:

```
   public class AsyncCustomTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return getEvacRouteNames();
            }

            @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
            // Function finished and value has returned.
        }

    }
```

And to call it:

```
new AsyncCustomTask().execute();
```

**Updated for second question**

For the method that have parameters, you can use constructor of your class like:

```
 public class AsyncSecondCustomTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, EvacRoute> {

        private final String routeName;
        private final LatLng currentLocation;
        private final String lat;
        private final String lon;

        public AsyncSecondCustomTask(String routeName, LatLng currentLocation, String lat, String lon) {
            this.routeName = routeName;
            this.currentLocation = currentLocation;
            this.lat = lat;
            this.lon = lon;
        }

        @Override
        protected EvacRoute doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return getEvacuationRoute(routeName, currentLocation, lat, lon);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(EvacRoute result) {
            // Function finished and value has returned.
        }

    }
```

And you can call it like:

```
new AsyncSecondCustomTask("", null, "", "").execute();
```

Comment: But I have two different webservice calls in the same class how do I do that?

Comment: And also how do I call this?

Comment: You can create different classes or objects instances for either one.

Comment: You can have two separate asynctasks running at the same time, or if they need to execute serially, you can have the first one call the second one from onPostExecute()

Comment: Ok but how do I call this from my activity?

Comment: My answer contains that question too: new AsyncCustomTask().execute();

Comment: Cool now on the method that has the parameters how do I do that  one? getEvacuationRoute(String routeName, LatLng currentLocation, String lat, String lon).