# How to use AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

**AsyncTask question**

I've followed some tutorials but it still isn't clear to me. Here's the code I currently have with some questions below the code. MainActivity calls SomeClassWithHTTPNeeds, which then calls the JSONParser (AsyncTask<>)

---

**MainActivity:**

```
String station = SomeClassWithHTTPNeeds.getInstance().getStation(123);
```

---

**SomeClassWithHTTPNeeds:**

```
getStation {

JSONParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject station = parser.getJSONFromUrl("https://api....");
return JSONObject.getString("station");
}
```

---

**JSONParser (AsyncTask< String, Void, String >)**

```
protected String doInBackground(); ==> Seperate thread
protected void onPostExecute(); ==> On GUI thread
```

I was thinking:
--- Put the HTTPRequest in doInBackground();

Problem is I'm not sure how to:
get the JSONParser to return the JSONObject to the getStation method?

**What I need to know**

=> Where should I return the JSONObject: in background or execute?

=> How do I use the JSONParser once it's an AsyncTask? Will the execute() function return the value?

=> AsyncTask< String, Void, String > ==> How does this work? It's the return type?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh also, I have never seen this notation: "doInBackground(String... arg) {", can somebody explain?

Comment: There are tons of examples about it. My answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577700/how-do-i-add-an-asynctask-to-this/16577742#16577742

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### FAQs and general explaination of the usage of AsyncTask

> => Where should I do network operations? Where should I return my aquired values?

In general, you should do Network Operations in a **Seperate Thread -> doInBackground();** since you do not want your UI to freeze when a Network Operation takes its time. So you should connect to your Service or .php script or wherever you get the Data from inside the `doInBackground()` method. Then you could also parse the data there and return the parsed data from the `doInBackground()` method by specifying the return type of `doInBackground()` to your desires, more about that down there. The `onPostExecute()` method will then receive your returned values from `doInBackground()` and represent them using the UI.

> => AsyncTask< String, Integer, Long> ==> How does this work?

In general, the `AsyncTask` class looks like this, which is nothing more than a generic class with 3 different [generic types](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm):

```
AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
```

> **You can specify the type of Parameter the `AsyncTask` takes, the Type of the Progress indicator and the type of the result (the return type
>   of doInBackGround()).**

Here is an Example of an `AsyncTask` looking like this:

```
AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long>
```

We have type String for the Parameters, Type Integer for the Progress and Type Long for the Result (return type of `doInBackground()`). **You can use any type you want for Params, Progress and Result.**

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {

 // these Strings / or String are / is the parameters of the task, that can be handed over via the excecute(params) method of AsyncTask
 protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {

    String param1 = params[0];
    String param2 = params[1];
    // and so on...
    // do something with the parameters...
    // be careful, this can easily result in a ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception
    // if you try to access more parameters than you handed over

    long someLong;
    int someInt;

    // do something here with params
    // the params could for example contain an url and you could download stuff using this url here

    // the Integer variable is used for progress
    publishProgress(someInt);

    // once the data is downloaded (for example JSON data)
    // parse the data and return it to the onPostExecute() method
    // in this example the return data is simply a long value
    // this could also be a list of your custom-objects, ...
    return someLong;
 }

 // this is called whenever you call puhlishProgress(Integer), for example when updating a progressbar when downloading stuff
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 // the onPostexecute method receives the return type of doInBackGround()
 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     // do something with the result, for example display the received Data in a ListView
     // in this case, "result" would contain the "someLong" variable returned by doInBackground();
 }
}
```

> => How to use AsyncTask? How can I "call" it? How can I "execute" it?

In this case, the AsyncTask takes a String or String Array as a **Parameter** which will look like this once the AsyncTask is called: **(The specified parameter is used in the execute(param) method of AsyncTask).**

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute("Somestring"); // some String as param
```

*Be aware, that this call **does not have a return value**, the only return value you should use is the one returned from `doInBackground()`. **Use the onPostExecute() method** do make use of the returned value.*

Also be careful with this line of code: (this execution will actually have a return value)

```
long myLong = new DownloadFilesTask().execute("somestring").get();
```

**The .get() call causes the UI thread to be blocked** (so the UI freezes if the operation takes longer than a few millisecons) while the AsyncTask is executing, because the execution **does not** take place in a separate thread. **If you remove the call to .get() it will perform asynchronously.**

> => What does this notation "execute(String... params)" mean?

This is a method with a so called "[varargs](http://www.journaldev.com/1257/java-variable-arguments-or-java-varargs-explained)" (variable arguments) parameter. To keep it simple, I will just say that it means that the actual **number of values you can pass on to the method via this parameter is not specified**, and any amount of values you hand to the method will be treated as an array inside the method. So this call could for example look like this:

```
execute("param1");
```

but it could however also look like this:

```
execute("param1", "param2");
```

or even more parameters. Assuming we are still talking about `AsyncTask`, the parameters can be accessed in this way in the `doInBackground(String... params)` method:

```
 protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {

     String str1 = params[0];
     String str2 = params[1]; // be careful here, you can easily get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException

     // do other stuff
 }
```

You can read more about AsyncTask here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Also take a look at this AsyncTask example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671602/1590502

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Exactly what I was looking for, detailed and brilliant! I've done what you said, and in order to catch the return value in the class executing the task, I've used the .execute().get(); method. It seems to be working great.

Comment: Allright, you are welcome. Nevertheless, be very careful with .get() -> see my edited answer.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed it, thanks for telling. In my case it's not a problem. However I'm not sure how it's possible to get the return value in the class executing the AsyncTask (in another way than .get())? What I need to execute can't be done in the onPostExecute() because I don't have access to the right variables. And I'd need to pass multiple types of variables to the AsyncTask to get them there. Otherwise I could define them as "Object" and then cast them to the right type? But it doesn't seem so proper :).

Comment: I assume that you are talking about variables that are inside your Activity? Simply make the AsyncTask an inner class of your activity. In that way you will have access to all the variables :)

Comment: I've made quite a few AsyncTasks now (without the .get()) and everything is running very fast and smoothly! This has definitely helped me.

Comment: `get()` is as bad as disabling `NetworkOnMainThreadException` when doing it without a thread since it is essentially the same result. You should IMO change "be careful" to **never use**.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.jsontest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;

public class HttpClient {
    private static final String TAG = "HttpClient";

    public static JSONObject SendHttpPost(String URL, JSONObject jsonObjSend) {

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);

            StringEntity se;
            se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString());

            httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
            httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"); 

            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
            Log.i(TAG, "HTTPResponse received in [" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-t) + "ms]");

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
                if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                    instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
                }

                String resultString= convertStreamToString(instream);
                instream.close();
                resultString = resultString.substring(0,resultString.length()-1); 

                JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString);
                Log.i(TAG,"<JSONObject>\n"+jsonObjRecv.toString()+"\n</JSONObject>");

                return jsonObjRecv;
            } 

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                Log.e("JSON", ""+line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Asynctask:

public class callCarWeb extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObjSend = new JSONObject();
            jsonObjSend.put("username", username);
            jsonObjSend.put("password", passwd);
            Log.e("SEND", jsonObjSend.toString());
            JSONObject json = HttpClient.SendHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/json/login.php", jsonObjSend);
            String status = json.getString("status");
            if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("pass")){
                String id = json.getString("user_id");
                Log.e("id", id);
                String name = json.getString("name");
                Log.e("name", name);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return null;
```

}

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        mDialog.cancel();
    }
```

}
    ## Heading ##

Answer (score 0):

I think you can execute your `HTTPRequest` in your `doInBackground` of the `Async` task. And `JSONParser` at `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 0):

do read some [generics.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

now, when you write your async task JSONParser here `params` is of type `String`, `progress` is of type `Void` and `result` is of type `String`. Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

generally people overrides two methods `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()`, the first one takes `params` and returns a `result` and second one takes that `result`. These are `protected` methods you can't call em directly. Then you might ask how to send `param` to `doInBackground()`, look at `execute()` API.

`doInBackground()` runs on background thread, its not a `blocking call`!!

don't do this,

```
JSONParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject station = parser.getJSONFromUrl("https://api....");
return JSONObject.getString("station");
```

instead write on `interface` in `JSONParser` or somewhere else like,

```
public interface OnParseCompleteListener {
     void onParseComplete(JSONObject obj);
}
```

now your `JSONParser` class will something like,

```
public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
     private OnParseCompleteListener mOnParseCompleteListener;

     public void setOnParseCompleteListener(OnParseCompleteListener listener) {
         mOnParseCompleteListener = listener;
     }

     protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         /*
          * do http request and return a result
          */
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String... result) {
         /*
          * parse the resulting json string or you can parse same string in 
          * doInBackground and can send JSONObject as a result directly.
          * at this stage say you have a JSONObject obj, follow 
          */
          if (mOnParseCompleteListener != null) {
              mOnParseCompleteListener.onParseComplete(obj);
          }
     }
}
```

when you create an object of `JSONParser` set `OnParseCompleteListener`.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
parser.setOnParseCompleteListener(listener);
parse.execute("may be an url");
```

now you decide from where to pass or create your own listener.