# How to fix NetworkonMainThreadException in Android?

Tags: java, android, networkonmainthread

I'm creating an project for assignment, I'm new to Android, and I wanted to access json from very common url `http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/`,

**Problem:** I'm trying to read the url and fetch and parse the json returned by this url,

I've already added following line into my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**Preferences:** and my android preferences are

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

1. Api level 18
2. Android 4.3

and this is how I'm trying to read the url

```
static InputStream is = null;

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

**The Error Message**

```
11-02 05:23:47.843: E/AndroidRuntime(2207): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 05:23:47.843: E/AndroidRuntime(2207): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.me.countrypedia/com.me.countrypedia.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-02 05:23:47.843: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-02 05:23:47.843: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-02 05:23:47.843: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-02 05:23:47.843: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
```

Also I'm following this tutorial for ListView Example
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: use a thread or asynctask . this should be executed on a thread `HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your `Exception` actually tells you exactly what you are doing wrong. You are not using another **thread** to perform **NetworkOperations**. Instead, you perform the network operation on your UI-Thread, which cannot (does not) work on Android.

Your code that connects to the url should be executed for example inside an **AsyncTasks** `doInBackground()` method, **off the UI-Thread.**

Take a look at this question on how to use the AsyncTask: **[How to use AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289623/how-to-use-asynctask/18289746#18289746)**

Answer (score 14):

**Updated Answer:**

Potentially long running operations such as **network** operations should be done in a worker thread.

The most effective way to create a worker thread for longer operations is with the [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class. Simply extend [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and implement the [doInBackground()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)) method to perform the work.

Many libraries are available to do network operations such as [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley), [retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) etc.

---

**Old Answer:**

Add following lines in your activity `onCreate` method

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 13):

Use following code.

```
private class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<String, String,String> {
     protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
        return null;
     }

 }
```

and in your ManinActivity Use following code.

```
new UpdateTask().execute();
```