# Android Execute Asyntask within another class from another class

Tags: android, class, android-asynctask

I have a class inside which there is another class that extends AsyncTask. As,

```
public class Dashboard extends Activity {
 -------------
 --------------
 --------------
  public class getUnreadMessageCount  extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(){
     *********some database stuff************
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
       count = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("messsage_count"));
       // Set Text to the textview
       messageCount.setText(count); 
    }

  }
}
```

Now I am using GCMIntentService Class for notification. How can I call and execute the `getUnreadMessageCount` in the following

```
private void sendNotification(String content_id, int type, String msg) {

}
```

I tried as

```
private void sendNotification(String content_id, int type, String msg) {
    Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard;
    dashboard.Dashboard dashboard---- 
}
```

But it does not work. How could I solve this problem.

Comment: `getUnreadMessageCount` why you call your AsyncTask like if it would be a method name?

Comment: Well I kinda have less knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

What I see here is **very bad style** and not according to the **[Java-Code-Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html)**. You are naming a `class` like a `method`. In java generally, all Class names are written in capital letters and should be **nouns**.

```
public class getUnreadMessageCount  extends AsyncTask
```

should be called (at least):

```
public class GetUnreadMessageCount  extends AsyncTask
```

or much better:

```
// make clear it is an async task
public class GetUnreadMessageCountTask  extends AsyncTask
```

This is how to start the `AsyncTask`:

```
private void sendNotification(String content_id, int type, String msg) {
     new GetUnreadMessageCountTask().execute();
}
```

The `execute(...)` method can also take **parameters**, depending on your specification of the `AsyncTask`. For a general explaination of the AsyncTask, have a look here: **[How to use AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289623/how-to-use-asynctask/18289746#18289746)**

Comment: I did change the class name to GetUnreadMessageCount as you've suggested. But I can call it only from the class within  . I cannot call It from any other class.

Comment: If you want to call it from another class, make a separate file for the GetUnreadMessageCount class and then import it wher you need it.

Comment: Yes, but I need to extend view if I need to access the Layout but how could I do it if I extend a class with AsyncTask. If you see my Class with AsyncTask I have implemented `count = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("messsage_count"));
       // Set Text to the textview
       messageCount.setText(count); `